# Replace table tags with p tags if found that result is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to replace the table tag in my html code with p tags denoting that "Result not found!" after searching but I am unsure how.

Controller

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @parameter = params[:search]
    @students = Student.all.where("name LIKE :search",search: @parameter)
    if @students.blank?
        redirect_to students_path
    end
  else
    @students = Student.all
  end
end
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Listing students</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="body" class="col-md-12">
      <%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'get' do%>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search,params[:search]%>
          <%= submit_tag "Search"%>
        </p>
      <%end%>
      <%= link_to 'New student', new_student_path %>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>

          <% @students.each do |student| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= student.name %></td>
              <td><%= student.student_id %></td>
              <td><%= student.course %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Show', student_path(student) %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student_path(student), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For now, I redirect to the index page as a stand-in. Any advice?

Comment: Can you share the html code?

Comment: @demir Sorry about that! The HTML code is now included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem in html

```
<% if @students.present? %>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    <% @students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.name %></td>
        <td><%= student.student_id %></td>
        <td><%= student.course %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', student_path(student) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student_path(student), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>
  <p>Result not found!</p>
<% end %>
```